# Sending errors of data to MongoDB when using Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have set all the cors correctly. MongoDB also seems to be perfect as when I using postman data can be send. data retrieval also can be done using localhost.

```
 **onSubmit(form:NgForm){
   console.log(form);
    this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log("testing3");
      this.resetForm(form);
      M.toast({html: 'saved successfully!',classes: 'rounded'});
    });**
```

This is function I used to send data. upto postEmployee this seems to be work as a tested using console.log().
This is the postEmployee function.

```
**import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Employee } from './employee.model';
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  selectedEmployee:Employee;
  employee:Employee[];
  readonly baseURL = 'https://localhost:3000/employees';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   postEmployee(emp:Employee){
    console.log("testing1");
    console.log(emp.name);

      return this.http.post(this.baseURL, emp);

  }
}**
```

I don't think there is a issue with the cors as I already imported them and use them correctly.

index.js file

```
**const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const cors = require ('cors');
const {mongoose} = require ('./db.js');
var employeeController = require('./controllers/employeeController.js');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:4200'}));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started at port :3000'));
app.use('/employees',employeeController);**
```

please can any one help me to resolve this issue?[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW1Uq.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MYlF.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8sYZ.jpg)

Comment: did it work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the Headers,

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json '})
}
```

and

```
 return this.http.post(this.baseURL, emp,httpOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks in advanced. As I forget to use the headers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just change 'https' into 'http' in your baseURL in EmployeeService. It worked for me!

Comment: Thank you in advance. I think the URL was the problem as I used readonly baseURL = 'https://localhost:3000/employees';. I mistakenly typed an extra "s" in http://.